# Auditing and @Embedded in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am having a problem with JPA auditing and for `@Embedded` members. Consider the following example scenario:

I set up a test table in an Oracle DB:

```
CREATE TABLE AUDIT_TEST (
  ID            NUMBER(38)   NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  CREATION_DATE TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

I define a JPA `@Entity` with auditing:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "AUDIT_TEST")
public class AuditTest {

  private Long id;
  private LocalDateTime creationDate;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID")
  public Long getId() { return id; }

  public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

  @CreatedDate
  @Column(name = "CREATION_DATE")
  public LocalDateTime getCreationDate() { return creationDate; }

  public void setCreationDate(LocalDateTime creationDate) {
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
  }

}
```

Finally, I enable JPA auditing in my `@Configuration`:

```
@SpringBootApplication()
@EnableJpaAuditing()
public class AuditTestApplication {
}
```

So far so good; when I construct an `AuditTest` instance, assign it an id and commit, the `creationDate` column gets populated with the current timestamp as expected.

However, things stop working when I encapsulate the audit column in an `@Embeddable`:

```
@Embeddable
public class AuditTestEmbeddable {

  private LocalDateTime creationDate;

  @CreatedDate
  @Column(name = "CREATION_DATE")
  public LocalDateTime getCreationDate() { return creationDate; }

  public void setCreationDate(LocalDateTime creationDate) {
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
  }

}
```

Then I change my entity class to embed the creation date:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "AUDIT_TEST")
public class AuditTest {

  private Long id;
  private AuditTestEmbeddable auditTestEmbeddable = new AuditTestEmbeddable();

  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID")
  public Long getId() { return id; }

  public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

  @Embedded
  public AuditTestEmbeddable getAuditTestEmbeddable() {
    return auditTestEmbeddable;
  }

  public void setAuditTestEmbeddable(AuditTestEmbeddable auditTestEmbeddable) {
    this.auditTestEmbeddable = auditTestEmbeddable;
  }

}
```

And unfortunately, the auditing is no longer working.

Is anyone here aware of a way to save the auditing functionality while still using `@Embedded` classes?

Comment: The information has to be on a managed entity (at least that is how it is done and works now). So currently there is no other way then to add it directly to the entity.

Comment: Hello, so the only available option is to add directly to every entity the needed fields, such as: User creator, User updater, Date creationDate, Date updateDate? Is it correct?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update:**
This functionality has been added to Spring Data 2.1 M2 (Lovelace).
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1274

Spring Data audit annotations in nested (embeddable) classes isn't supported yet. Here's [the jira ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1274) requesting this feature.

However, we could use custom audit listener to set audit information in embeddable classes.

Here's the sample implementation taken from a blog: [How to audit entity modifications using the JPA @EntityListeners, @Embedded, and @Embeddable annotations](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-audit-entity-modifications-using-the-jpa-entitylisteners-embedded-and-embeddable-annotations/).

**Embeddable Audit**

```
@Embeddable
public class Audit {

    @Column(name = "created_on")
    private LocalDateTime createdOn;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(name = "updated_on")
    private LocalDateTime updatedOn;

    @Column(name = "updated_by")
    private String updatedBy;

    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

**Audit Listener**

```
public class AuditListener {

    @PrePersist
    public void setCreatedOn(Auditable auditable) {
        Audit audit = auditable.getAudit();

        if(audit == null) {
            audit = new Audit();
            auditable.setAudit(audit);
        }

        audit.setCreatedOn(LocalDateTime.now());
        audit.setCreatedBy(LoggedUser.get());
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void setUpdadtedOn(Auditable auditable) {
        Audit audit = auditable.getAudit();

        audit.setUpdatedOn(LocalDateTime.now());
        audit.setUpdatedBy(LoggedUser.get());
    }
}
```

**Auditable**

```
public interface Auditable {

    Audit getAudit();

    void setAudit(Audit audit);
}
```

**Sample Entity**

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditListener.class)
public class Post implements Auditable {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Embedded
    private Audit audit;

    private String title;

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

With spring-data 2.4.4 the AuditListener works fine with embedded objects, see
[documentation spring-data](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/2.4.4/reference/html/#auditing.annotations)

The minimal version of spring-data is bundled in spring-boot version 2.4.3

Comment: Do you have a working example? The documentation is not very extensive and does not seem to work with the latest spring boot 2.6.2 :-(

Comment: It seems that it's not working on Spring Data JPA v2.7.12.