# Increment @version when an entity is embedded in an @embeddable

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I know there is a similar question listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38244498/auditing-and-embedded-in-spring-data-jpa) but in my own case, I don't have the dates across . Rather, I have an embedded class with an entity in it.
I have the below entity definitions:

**Person JPA Entity**

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Person {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @CreatedDate
    private OffsetDateTime creationDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private OffsetDateTime updatedDate;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    @Embedded
    private ContactAddress contactAddress;
}
```

**ContactAddress JPA Entity**

```
@Embeddable
public class ContactAddress {
    private String notice;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "former_street_id")
    private Street formerStreet;

      @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "new_street_id")
    private Street newStreet;
}
```

**Street JPA Entity**

```
@Table(name = "p_street")
public class Street  {
    @Id
    private int id;

    private String line1;
    private String line2;
}
```

The Street JPA entity is a field of the ContactAddress class. When I update a ContactAddress instance, the version in the Person entity is incremented provided it is the ***'notice'*** field of the ContactAddress that is changed. If however, I update any of the Street Object fields, the version is not incremented.
The reason being that I am definitely missing how to notify the auditingEntityListner to raise an event on the updateDate field on the Person entity.

It appears, with
me having the Street entity in the embedded ContactAddress, a disconnect has been created between the Person entity and the Street entity. Is there a way to fix this in JPA?

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected becauyse when you modify `Street`, you are not modifying, only some entity in different table. Person (person table) itself is unchanged thus no increment in version.

When you modify `ContactAddress`, since it is a "part of Person" (literally a set of columns in person table - thus person), you are modifying row in person entry, therfore version is bumped up.

If you need to version to bumped up (I would rather not) you have to "touch" `Person` when you are modifying `Street` entity. I dont know if there is an auto way of doing it.

Keep in mind, that your intention is to potentially increment version of multiple person entries when you modify address as address might be used in multiple person entries.

Comment: I totally agree that when I modify Street, I am not modifying Person but I want a way that when I modify Street, Person entity
So, I am hoping there is a way to tie the Street entity to the Person entity while still keeping it as a field reference in the ContactAddress.
I am assuming there must be a way to automatically trigger the version increment when the Street table is updated.

Comment: I don't know of any (does not mean there is none). However, it is a single update query, increment version by 1 where contactAddres_id=x`. Keep in mind you should not only update ALL rows in Person table that uses the same id but other entities as well, in order to be consistent.

Comment: Thanks Antoniossss, I suppose there is a way. I was looking into OPTIMISTIC_FORCE as a means to somehow achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that the `@Version` field is increased then:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public void savePerson(Person p) {

    em.lock(p, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);
}
```

This way the person's `version` field is always increased.

Note that the `version` field is increased by two if the Envers framework is aware of an change, e.g. when `notice` has been modified.